# Set custom background image in videocall, it's possible?

Tags: skype

it's possibile to set up a custom image in the videocall with Skype? I want set a static image during videocall.

Answer (score 0):

try below three...

- Specifically for Skype, there's [magic camera](http://shop.skype.com/apps/Games-and-entertainment/Magic-Camera.html) under Skype Apps on their "extras" page.
- another one [many cam](http://manycam.com/) allows you to add backgrounds / borders / overlays to the feed from your web camera - and it runs under windows. There is a free version too.
- one more is called [video skin](http://videoskin.net/about)  is a unique software that allows the user to add a Flash® animated backdrops that will enhance a webcam experience. Through a simple process, Flash® animations can be applied to be a foreground or background. Compatible with almost all video-chatting software including Skype, CAMFROG®, Paltalk Scene, ICQ® and others

Answer (score 0):

The link of Magic Camera is broken, because third party applications that work with Skype will no longer be supported starting December 2013

Answer (score -1):

Since version 8 it is possible to change the background effect (either blur the background or choose a custom background image) via Audio & Video settings.

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] your answer to indicate *how* you can do this?